# if an item in a list doesn't match a column name in a data frame, produce exception statement

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I have the following code which creates a list, takes inputs of column names the user wants, then a for loop applies each list attribute individually to check in the if statement if the user input matches the columns in the data frame.

Currently this produces an exception handling statement if all inputs to the list are unmatching, but if item in the list matches the column in the dataframe but others do not, then jupyter will produce its own error message "KeyError: "['testcolumnname'] not in index", because it is trying to move onto the else part of my statement and create the new dataframe with this but it cant (because those columns do not exist)

I want it to be able to produce this error message 'Attribute does not exist in Dataframe. Make sure you have entered arguments correctly.' if even 1 inputted list attribute does not match the dataframe and all other do. But Ive been struggling to get it to do that, and it produces this KeyError instead.

My code:

```
    lst = []  
    lst = [item for item in str(input("Enter your attributes here: ")).lower().split()]        
    for i in lst:
        if i not in df.columns:
            print('Attribute does not exist in Dataframe. Make sure you have entered arguments correctly.')
            break
        else:
            df_new = df[lst]
            # do other stuff
```

for example if i have a dataframe:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NA | yes | yes |
| yes | no | yes |

and my list contains:

```
['A','B','C']
```

It works correctly, and follows the else statement, because all list items match the dataframes columns so it has no problem.

Or if it has this:

```
['x','y','z']
```

It will give the error message I have, correctly. Because no items match the data frames items so it doesn't continue.

But if it is like this, where one attribute is matching the dataframe, and others not...

```
['A','D','EE']
```

it gives the jupyter KeyError message but I want it to bring back the print message i created ('Attribute does not exist in Dataframe. Make sure you have entered arguments correctly.').

The KeyError appears on the line of my else statement: 'df_new = df[lst]'

Can anyone spot an issue i have here that will stop it from going this? Thank you all

Comment: Think carefully about your logic. In the case where every `i` is `in df.columns`, how many times do you expect the `else` block to be entered? How many times do you *want* that code to run, in that case? It sounds like conceptually what you're trying to do is figure out whether *all* of the `i` values are `in df.columns` (equivalently, whether *any* of them is *not*), right? So, you want to structure the code to *figure that out first*, and then act on the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to print, but to raise exception
And you need to fix your indentation

```py
lst = []  
lst = [item for item in str(input("Enter your attributes here: ")).lower().split()]        
for i in lst:
    if i not in df.columns:
        raise ValueError('Attribute does not exist in Dataframe. Make sure you have entered arguments correctly.')
df_new = df[lst]
# do other stuff
```